# Android. Countdownlatch.await does not work

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I dont know what I am doing wrong here. Countdownlatch.await does not work. There is absolutely no wait time. I have tested with absurd numbers (50 seconds) and had the call afterwords come instantly. I am trying to use it on the UI thread. I also have another thread running.

Code:

```
private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1); //called earlier

void someMethod() {
  //code
   Runnable flashScreen = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            flashScreen();
        }
    };

    runOnUiThread(flashScreen);
    //Mode code
}

private void flashScreen()
{
    final TextView monthDayYear = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.month_day_year);
    final TextView hourMinuteSecond = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hour_minute_second);
    //Get date and time
    final SyncModule syncModule = _application.getSyncModule();
    syncModule.start();

    while(counter.intValue() < 150) {
        try {
            //Thread.sleep(10);
            latch.countDown();
            latch.await(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            counter.incrementAndGet();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Util.appendLog("SyncActivity: InterruptedException while flashing camera " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    final ImageView fadeView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.sync_flash_rectangle);
    fadeView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    fadeIn(fadeView, 1, 0, 1000, true);

    Calendar syncTime = syncModule.getDateAndTime();

    monthDayYear.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(syncTime.getTime()));
    hourMinuteSecond.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:00").format(syncTime.getTime()));

    try {
        latch.countDown();
        latch.await(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Util.appendLog("SyncActivity: InterruptedException while flashing camera " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    counter.set(1000);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure that you understand how a `CountDownLatch` works.  The `countDown()` method and the `await()` method are generally called in separate threads.

From the Java8 JavaDoc for [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html):

> A CountDownLatch is initialized with a given count. The await methods block until the current count reaches zero due to invocations of the countDown() method, after which all waiting threads are released and any subsequent invocations of await return immediately. This is a one-shot phenomenon -- the count cannot be reset. If you need a version that resets the count, consider using a CyclicBarrier.

In your current code, you have a countdown of 1 for your latch (from the first line of your example `new CountDownLatch(1);`).  In both locations that you are calling `await()`, you are immediately prior calling `countDown()`, which is causing the countdown of your latch to reach 0 (or even less).  Thus, any calls to `await()` will not even block, since the countdown has already been reached.

It is not immediately clear to me what you are trying to accomplish, but if you give more details, I may be able to provide further advice.

Comment: +1. Essentially, OP, you're saying "I'm ready. Now, wait till I'm ready." The second one of those statements returns instantly, because of the first.

Comment: I want to wait 10 ms before incrementing the `AtomicLong` counter, as I want to "synchronize" two items so that they occur at the same time (line up a camera and screen flash). The wait is done to ensure that the camera has had enough time to turn on, as that seems to be very slow.

Comment: I would rather use a `Thread.sleep(10)` call, but that freezes the UI thread (as expected). I may just have to tweek how everything works, and run the UI updates on the thread (separate from the counter)

Comment: For executing code at some point in the future check out the class `ScheduledExecutorService`. The `Executors` class provides factory methods to construct these.